# Video on Blackberry Smartphones?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm, video-encoding

What video codecs and file formats does the Curve and Storm support?

Answer (score 1):

See this document: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/smartphone_users/deliverables/15801/711-01774-123_Supported_Media_Types_on_BlackBerry_Smartphones.pdf